# CTE WITH RECURSIVE Up and back? How do I get the whole tree from any node?

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Given a very simplistic table like:

```
-- SQLite3
CREATE TABLE tst (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    parent_id INTEGER CHECK (parent_id <> id),
    tag STRING NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES tst(id)
    )
```

I can use `WITH RECURSIVE` (common table expressions) to go from any node up to the "root" of that tree or to traverse downward from a node to all of its children (along all branches). Here are the queries that seem to work for those two cases (respectively):

```
    WITH RECURSIVE t(id, parent_id, tag) AS (
        SELECT id, parent_id, tag FROM tst WHERE id=:mynode
      UNION ALL
        SELECT t2.id, t2.parent_id, t2.tag FROM tst AS t2
        JOIN t ON t.parent_id = t2.id
    ) SELECT * FROM t
```

... and:

```
    WITH RECURSIVE t(id, parent_id, tag) AS (
        SELECT id, parent_id, tag FROM tst WHERE id=?
      UNION ALL
        SELECT t2.id, t2.parent_id, t2.tag FROM tst AS t2
        JOIN t ON t.id = t2.parent_id
    ) SELECT * FROM t
```

(All I've done is reverse `t.parent_id` and `t2.id` from the first example into the other).

That works like a charm.  But I'm trying to wrap my head around how I would start from any node and get the whole group of rows.

The obvious workaround would be to perform the first query, find the row where `parent_id IS NULL` then perform the second query on that. But I figure there must be a more elegant solution.

What is it?

Comment: If your table may contain several trees, then I can't think of another solution, other than you suggested. You need to find the root of the tree first somehow and then traverse the whole tree down from the root. If your table can contain only one tree, then you can find the root without recursion, using simple `WHERE parent_id IS NULL`. I don't think it is possible to traverse in both directions (up and down) in the same query simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that my earlier RCTE query worked but had two major flaws for my application.

- I wasn't capturing the depth for each row; so I couldn't easily indent my entries to reflect the thread nesting level
- My `ORDER BY` clause was completely off base ... so even if I indented each row according to its nesting depth the resulting "outline summary" would be completely wrong.

This slightly more complicated query seems to solve both of those problems:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree (id, parent_id, tag, depth, path) AS (
  SELECT id, parent_id, tag, 1 AS depth, '' AS path FROM tst WHERE id = (
    WITH RECURSIVE t3 (id, parent_id) AS (
      SELECT id, parent_id FROM tst WHERE id = :mynode
      UNION ALL
      SELECT t2.id, t2.parent_id FROM tst AS t2
      JOIN t3 ON t3.parent_id=t2.id
     ) SELECT id FROM t3 WHERE parent_id IS NULL
   ) UNION ALL
     SELECT t2.id, t2.parent_id, t2.tag, tree.depth+1,
        path || '/' || CAST(t2.id AS VARCHAR) FROM tst AS t2
     JOIN tree ON tree.id = t2.parent_id
 ) SELECT * FROM tree ORDER by path;
```

... SO doesn't seem to let me mark-up the contents of my code here ... but I'm adding the `depth` and `path` columns to the "tree" (CTE virtual) table, supplying initial values for those (virtual) columns in my first `SELECT` (using `1 AS depth, '' AS path` (that's a new trick right for me right there), and then modifying those at every step through the recursion with `tree.depth+1, path || '/' || CAST(t2.id AS VARCHAR)`; then, finally I can use `path` for my `ORDER BY` and use the depth in my app to prefix each line with an appropriate level of indentation.

To get this working for my application I can do something like:

```
#!python
for each in db.execute("SELECT id FROM tst WHERE parent_id IS NULL").fetchall():
    for row in db.execute(qry, each):
        print("%s\t%s%s" % (row[0], '  ' * row[3], row[2]))
```

... where `qry` is the query I've describe above (actually adjusted to fetch only the columns of interest, but this example works even with `*` there).  In practice I might use LIMIT and OFFSET to page through those results (as I already do for the flat list of results from the table that doesn't support any message threading).

Also I'm aware that the `CHECK` I put on the table schema for this was only preventing the most trivial form of circular tree.  It seems like `parent_id INTEGER CHECK (parent_id IS NULL or parent_id < id)` should work better.  (Each chain of parent_id -> id links must be monotonically decreasing ... so no cycle is possible.  The `FOREIGN KEY` enforces that property for `INSERT` statements already ... but this check enforcement is for `UPDATE` as well.  (Technically I suppose I should use the "date" fields in my actual application, but I hope the surrogate key is sufficient).

BTW: Shout out to: a_horse_with_no_name for this posting: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7150 ... which helped me figure out how to build the paths.

Comment: Came up with a couple more variants ... one to fetch *all* threads ordered by path, and another to fetch only the most recent entries in each thread (the tails from each root entry).

I won't post them here unless someone asks for them; but SQLFiddle doesn't seem to be letting me continue to fiddle with the earlier posting. :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've now spent some time with [SQLFiddle: PostgreSQL: CTE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d3654/18) and this seems to work:

```
-- SQL: Fetch whole tree
WITH RECURSIVE t (id, parent_id, tag) AS
 (
  SELECT id, parent_id, tag FROM tst WHERE id =
   (
    WITH RECURSIVE t3 (id, parent_id) AS
     (
      SELECT id, parent_id FROM tst WHERE id = :mynode
      UNION ALL
      SELECT t2.id, t2.parent_id FROM tst AS t2
      JOIN t3 ON t3.parent_id=t2.id 
     ) SELECT id FROM t3 WHERE parent_id IS NULL
   ) UNION ALL
     SELECT t2.id, t2.parent_id, t2.tag FROM tst AS t2
     JOIN t ON t.id = t2.parent_id
 ) SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY id;
```

... where `:mynode` is the ID of any node in a given tree of rows.

All I'm doing is taking the first query (walk up the tree), adding `WHERE parent_id IS NULL` to get just the parent of that whole tree, and pasting it into an `IN (...)` expression.  (In this case I could also just use `=` rather than `IN`).

That still looks a bit, ummm, ... involved.  But it does seem to work.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Also this is my first time using SQLFiddle to post or answer a question.  I'm hoping I've done it properly and that folks can follow the link at see what I'm talking about.  I used PostgreSQL because the version of SQLite on SQLFiddle seems to be too old to support CTEs; but my question was more about CTEs than about SQLite3's specific implementation.